# iOS/Swift/Parse - Struct not storing data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm having trouble storing data from Parse in a Struct. I have set up my UITableViewController to use a separate Struct file to get/manage data from Parse. The struct initially gets the data from Parse (confirmed using println), but when I then try and reference the data to populate the table, the struct is then empty again. Below are the 2 files (several methods omitted to try and make it more concise here). I previously had this working correctly when I used a separate class (instead of a struct) to get the Parse data, but have since decided a struct would be better for my needs. Can anyone spot what is going wrong with the struct? Many thanks.

### Console Output

> resultsArray.count = 45 filled objectList.count = 1 objects at
>   index0.count = 45 testPrint objectList.count = 0

### UITableViewController

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ExerciseMuscleTypeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  //  MARK: Variables

  var citadel: Citadel = Citadel()

  //  MARK: IBActions

  @IBAction func refreshButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    citadel.testPrint()
  }

  //  MARK: Override

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    citadel = Citadel(parseClassName: "ExerciseList", orderedBy: "MusclePrimary")
  } 
}
```

### Struct connecting to Parse

```
import Foundation
import Parse

struct Citadel {

  //  MARK: Properties

  var objectList: [[PFObject]] = [[PFObject]]()
  var sectionHeaders: [String] = [String]()
  var parseClassName: String?
  var userID: String?

  //  MARK: Methods

  func testPrint() {
    println("testPrint, objectList.count = \(self.objectList.count)")
  }

  //  MARK: Init

  init(parseClassName: String, orderedBy: String) {

    //    Set structure's properties

    self.parseClassName = parseClassName
    self.objectList = [[PFObject]]()
    self.sectionHeaders.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    if let id = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId {
      self.userID = id
    }

    //  Format query to get data from Parse

    var query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)
    query.orderByAscending(orderedBy)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (queryResult: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

      if let resultsArray = queryResult as? [PFObject] {
        println("resultsArray.count = \(resultsArray.count)")
        self.objectList = [resultsArray]
        println("filled objectList.count = \(self.objectList.count)")
        println("objects at index0.count = \(self.objectList[0].count)")

      }
    }
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue could be because you're initializing your struct as a variable here: `var Citadel = Citadel()`, but then you're also reinitializing it in `viewDidLoad`. I would try declaring your `var` as `var Citadel: Citadel?` and then initialize it as you were in `viewDidLoad` and see if that helps you out.

Comment: I changed it to be an optional, but when running the IBAction refreshButton I still get the printout from the console "testPrint, objectList.count = 0"